# Instantiating a generic class in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, instance

I have the following first generic class and its interface:

```
    public interface Generic1Interface<E extends Comparable> {
    ..
    }

    public class Generic1 <E extends Comparable> implements 
    Generic1Interface<E>  {
    .. //implementation of Doubly linked list using Node objects
    }
```

And the second generic class and its interface:

```
    public interface Generic2Interface<E extends Comparable> {
    ..
    }

    public class Generic2 <E extends Comparable> implements 
    Generic22Interface<E>  {
      Generic1Interface<E> list;
        //so nothing here but a reference to an object of type Generic1Interface<E>
    Generic2() {
      list = new Generic1();
    }
```

Suppose we're working on a method inside the second class, and we try to instantiate a new instance of the second class, and name it "result", then try to access its Generic2 instance, it will give an error:

```
    public Generic2Interface<E> union (E a, E b) {
      Generic2Interface<E> result = new Generic2();
      **result.list** = ....;
```

result.list will give an error: "list cannot be resolved or is not a field". I think there must be a workaround to instantiate a generic class in a generic class. 
Thanks.

EDIT: I need to conform to the interfaces in each implemented class. So as you can see the method union has to return object of type Generic2Interface that's why I declare result like this.

Comment: Isn't a cast to Generic2 necessary before you try to access a field defined in that class? As of now, result is of type Generic2Interface..

Comment: If I read your code correctly you try to access the list field on an object of type Generic2Interface. This field is not defined on the interface, but on the Generic2 class.

Comment: @RobObdeijn Correct. I forgot to mention the reason I'm doing this. I have to conform to the interface so I need to deal with instances of type Generic2 but at the end of each method in this class I have to return object type Generic2Interface<E>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cast for result to `Generic2` type. This works:

`System.out.println(((Generic2)result).list);`

Or this:

```
Generic2<E> result = new Generic2();
System.err.println(result.list);
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. What I actually tried was:
`Generic2Interface<E> result = new Generic2();` then 
`result = (Generic2) result;` but still I couldn't access result.list.

Comment: That's not what I've suggested. `Set` is from a different type hierarchy and isn't compatible with Generic2Interface. You need to use the type where you've defined the field `list`, which is *only* Generic2 and not any other type.

Comment: I need to conform to the interfaces, so I can't declare result like this: `Generic2<E> result = ...`

Comment: Not a problem, then you can use the first option i.e. wherever you need to access `list`, do a cast there to `Generic2`. The point still stands - you can only access `list` *on* a variable of type Generic2.

Comment: I understood your point. I tried casting, but it appears that a simple cast like this is not working: `Generic2Interface<E> result = new Generic2();` then `result = (Generic2) result;` I still couldn't access list.

Comment: Assigning the typecast value to `result` doesn't change the type of `result`. Its type still remains as Generic2Interface, which doesn't have anything called list inside. Only if you typecast and access `list` at the same time, it will work i.e. `((Generic2)result).list`